# updating jpeg properties in c++ using GDI+

Tags: c++, gdi+, exif

I am tring to copy properties from one jpeg image to another in c++. As I don't have any library and I am working on windows, I am using GDI+ for this.
My code is as follow

```
 void CopyJpegProperties(string targetImageName,string sourceImageName)
    {
        CLSID  m_clsid;
        EncoderParameters m_encoderParameters;
        UINT size;
        UINT count;
        int quality=100;
        GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
        ULONG_PTR m_gdiplusToken;
        // start GDI+
        GdiplusStartup(&m_gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);
        {
            // we are processing images inside a block to make sure that all of objects are deleted when GDI is shutdown.

            // read source image properties
            std::wstring wcSourceImageName=StringTools::StringToWString(sourceImageName);
            Gdiplus::Bitmap sourceBitmap(wcSourceImageName.c_str());
            sourceBitmap.GetPropertySize(&size, &count);
            PropertyItem* pPropBuffer =(PropertyItem*)malloc(size);
            sourceBitmap.GetAllPropertyItems(size, count, pPropBuffer);

            // write to target image
            std::wstring wcTargetImageName=StringTools::StringToWString(targetImageName);
            Gdiplus::Bitmap targetBitmap(wcTargetImageName.c_str());
            for(int i=0; i<count; i++)
            {
                targetBitmap.SetPropertyItem(&pPropBuffer[i]);
            }
            JpegTools::GetEncoderClsid(L"image/jpeg", &m_clsid);
            m_encoderParameters.Count = 1;
            m_encoderParameters.Parameter[0].Guid = EncoderQuality;
            m_encoderParameters.Parameter[0].Type = EncoderParameterValueTypeLong;
            m_encoderParameters.Parameter[0].NumberOfValues = 1;
            m_encoderParameters.Parameter[0].Value = &quality;

            Status stat = targetBitmap.Save(wcTargetImageName.c_str(), &m_clsid, &m_encoderParameters);
             if(stat != Ok)
              {
                 throw exception("Error in saving");
               }
        }
        GdiplusShutdown(m_gdiplusToken);
    }
```

This function fails with error code 7 which win32error.

I think the problem is that when I open the target file I can not write to it as it is locked by open function.

How can I fix it?

Is there any better way to read/write image properties in windows?

Comment: if you're working on anything newer than XP then [tag:WIC] may be a better choice as you don't need to load the entire image to manipulate the metadata. [Windows Imaging Component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee719653(v=vs.85).aspx). On a side note this code isn't exception safe, if that exception is thrown GDI+ won't be shut down.

Comment: @Mgetz Thanks, I will look at WIC to see how I can do this with WIC.